# python vs pyx in vim

Tags: vimrc, vimscript-python

I'm a bit confused as to what the difference is between `python` and `pyx` in vim, other than one seems to work and the other does not. For example:

```
pyx print ("OK")
```

This works, however, this does not:

```
python << EOF
    print 'OK'
EOF
```

And this does not:

```
:python print "Hello"
```

> E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version

What is the difference between the two? `:h python` is quite extensive, but every single command it gives does not work with the above command (though `pyx` does work).

Is `pyx` is the proper alias for `python` now?

```
pyx << END_OF_PYTHON

  import uuid
  my_id = (uuid.uuid4())
  vim.command("let my_id='%s'" % my_id)

END_OF_PYTHON

echom "The UUID4 is: " .my_id

" The UUID4 is: 1c131603-1b3f-4eb4-b8c8-ec600dc78628
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the `py*x` functions and commands permits to dynamically change which flavour of python is used -- through a global option.

`python` means python2. `python3` means ... v 3. And unfortunately once one has been successfully used, or even tested :(, the other one can no longer be used. IIRC, This also impacts which flavour of python `py*x` can target.

IMO, we should no longer use `python` or `python3` unless our code cannot work with the other python flavour. With `py*x` we can have portable code.